# GridSplitter getting stuck after dragging some pixels

Tags: c#, wpf, draggable, gridsplitter

GridSplitter getting stuck after dragging some pixels,and have to reselect the splitter and drag again.

I am using RadTreeView in one column, and ListBox in second column, in which user can select Item from ListBox and Drag it into RadTreeView.

Please find below screenshot for the UI.

I tried to find solution on SO, but not getting any useful answer.

Please find below code for the same, Let me know if you require more information for the same.

[image: Screenshot of Window]

```
<UserControl x:Class="StructureDesigner.StructureDesigner"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:dragDrop="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.DragDrop;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StructureDesigner.ViewModel"             
    MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400" AllowDrop="True" telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag="True" Name="StructureDesignerScreen">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadTreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowDrag" Value="True" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag" Value="True" />
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="10" Background="DarkGray" Height="Auto"   />

        <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="radStructureTreeView" IsDragTooltipEnabled="True" IsDragDropEnabled="True"
                             IsDragPreviewEnabled="True" IsDropPreviewLineEnabled="True"
                             Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Extended"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,11,2" IsLoadOnDemandEnabled="True"
                             LoadOnDemand="radStructureTreeView_LoadOnDemand"
                             ExpanderStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle}"
                             IsExpandOnSingleClickEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding StructureDesignerList}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigationTemplate}"
                             telerik:TreeViewSettings.DragDropExecutionMode="New"
                             >

        </telerik:RadTreeView>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="gridEntities" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,2,2,2">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     SelectionMode="Extended" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding EntityList}"
                     AllowDrop="True">
                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Hide posted entities" Tag="Hide posted entities" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsHidePostedEntitiesChecked}"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Name="lblSpacer1" Height="5"></Label>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="25" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                                <Label Content="" Width="1" Height="16"  ></Label>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Label Name="lblSpacer2" Height="5"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Could it be that your mouse is having a bad time?

Comment: It would be good,If you provide some hint, What you mean by "mouse having a bad time" ?

Comment: Is your mouse broken? That it doesn't register a click/drag that well.
Had it happen to me before, bought a new mouse that fixed it.
Can you try to plug in another mouse and see what happens?

Comment: Mouse is absolutely working fine.Thanks for looking into this.!

Comment: I think the drag drop is probably causing this. You could try confirming that by disabling drag drop temporarily. You could also try giving the gridsplitter it's own column in the grid. I'd set it's verticalalignment stretch as well. You might have to replace the Telerik drag drop with code of your own.

Comment: @Andy Thank You, I have tried to use gridsplitter in separate columns and set verticalalignment to stretch as well, but it didn't solved the issue. I will check to disable drag and drop.

Comment: @Andy I had disabled capture drag on user control and It Worked. (telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag="False"), thanks for your hint.